# Update (master) gridview row after detailgrid has been generated

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a Gridview that contains detail grids that are incorported as an asp:TemplateField. This solution works very nice (see screendump)
[image]

The sql behind these grids is extremely costly, so i want to minimize the use for it.

The detail grids contain a margin (begrote marge). The average of that must be in te master row (in the column 'Begrote Marge')
I want to do this WITHOUT calculating this via the database, because it is too costly. so hence my question:
Is there any way to use some javascript to calculate the margins clientside and enter the answer in the master row, after the detail gridview has been generated?

- if there is any way to do this via .net, it would be acceptable too!
  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no one answered. Here is how i finally solved this problem:

I greated a table (tblCursussen). In the rowdatabound of the detail grid, i added the margins. I also kept class variable for the master course and a counter for the number of additions the 'total' margin comprised off.  With this information,

In the rowdatabound for the mastergrid, the method is started that fills the detail grid. So after the detailgrid has been generated, the class variables are filled with the appropriate figures. Once that has been acchieved, the margins in the masterrow can be calculated from the class variables, later in the rowdatabound of the mastergrid.